# Is it possible to define a topology on a set such that continuity of a map out of this space implies that map is an isometry?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, isometry

I understand that the use of defining a topology on a set is to define what it means for a map out of the space to be continuous. It is then natural to ask for which types of maps out of a set  is it possible to define a topology on the set to allow *only* said maps to be continuous (e.g. any map continuity -> discrete topology, 'traditional' continuity -> euclidean topology).

This has not yet been addressed in the textbook I am currently reading so I decided to take it here.

My question is specifically about isometric maps, but any more general answer will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to talk about "isometry", you need a "metric".

In a general topological space, this is no metric and the topology is not necessarily metrizable.

If you do have a metric space $(X,d)$, then the natural topology is the metric topology induced by the metric $d$. One can then ask whether a continuous function with respect to this topology is an isometry.

But there is no reason for an arbitrary continuous map to be an isometry: you can always consider the constant map.

Comment: Ok, but obviously the natural topology on such a metric space doesn't cut it. But is it possible to define some other topology on the metric space that does the job is my question.

Comment: @KillianHeanue: whatever topology you define, you can always consider the constant map, which is continuous.

Comment: that's not an issue as the constant map is an isometry.

Comment: @KillianHeanue: no, the constant map is not an isometry. The constant map is not the same as the "identity" map.

Comment: You are correct. So in the case of isometries, it is not possible to achieve this. The follow up question is "for which types of maps out of a set is it possible to define a topology on the set such that exactly those maps are the continuous maps?".

Comment: @KillianHeanue: you can take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118453/discussion-between-killian-heanue-and-mrsamy).

Comment: @KillianHeanue: sorry I have to go now. you can leave questions there and I may be back.